# Where are filesystem full event logged?

Tags: linux, logging, filesystems

I forced a filesystem to be 100% full. I am able to generate a message to STDOUT:

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=reallylargefile count=2097152
dd: writing to `reallylargefile': No space left on device
1018761+0 records in
1018760+0 records out
521605120 bytes (522 MB) copied, 73.9457 seconds, 7.1 MB/s
```

But I cannot find it in any of the logs (/var/log/messages etc). Where are these events registered? dmesg also does not indicate anything. Do I need to up the verbosity of syslogd?

cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have some kind of monitoring set up or some other service complains about missing disk space, it will not be logged.

Comment: Thanks. Odd. Most (if not all) flavors of *NIX do this out of the box. Looks as though Linux deals with this differently.